# how to get regex to get a string with space in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i want to get string data from the paragraph, in string there will a space.

sample data

```
my id is REG #22334 E112233
my name is xyz
my city is xyz
```

Expected op = `22334 E112233`

code

```
var myString= "my id is REG #22334 E112233
my name is xyz
my city is xyz";
var regex = new Regex(@"[1-3]\d{4}([ ]E\d{6})?$");
var id= regex.Match(myString).Value;

O/p = "";
```

Comment: `[ ]E` looks like a complicated way of writing `<space>E` (where `<space>` is an actual space). Also, your regex [seems to be working](https://regex101.com/r/dXiu50/1).

Comment: `var id = Regex.Match(myString, @"[1-3][0-9]{4}(?: E[0-9]{6})?$");`

Comment: Does it _have to_ be a Regex? Data seems to be pretty simple prefixed by "my id is REG #" ?

Comment: ^^ => https://dotnetfiddle.net/quNvhw

Comment: i want to validate the reg id which starts with 1 to 3 number  and have 4 digits after that E and 6 digits

Comment: @TedLyngmo its working in regex site but not in c# code in vs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you match at the end of the line with `$` you need to use the multiline option:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        var myString= @"my id is REG #22334 E112233
        my name is xyz
        my city is xyz";
        var regex = new Regex(@"[1-3]\d{4}(?: E\d{6})?$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var id= regex.Match(myString).Value;

        Console.WriteLine(id);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
22334 E112233
```

Comment: Tested @ [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match?view=net-7.0#code-try-3). Empty the code window and paste my code in it. It should run automatically and display the expected result.

Comment: hi its working but i have an issue with that , few data is still matching wrongly like "12345" which is not a valid one. it should start with 1 3 and should have E after that it should have 6 digits. can u help me on regex also

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mrnb3S/1

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I'm sorry, but I don't understand what to do with that. Please post a new question about how to fine tune the regex so it only matches your specific criteria (and include details that makes it hard to come up with a regex that fails where it should match or match where it should fail). You may put a link here if you post a new question and I'll come by to see if I can solve it.